# Excel Remove Blank or Zero But Keep Dupliacate Value

Tags: excel

I want to skip the values from entire column where cells value is 0, however I want to leave the duplicate values still displayed.

I tried to do things such as

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C6:$G6; MATCH(0; INDEX(COUNTIF($J6:J6;$C6:$G6); 0; 0); 0)); "")
```

I've attached to screeenshot to help

[image]

Comment: Please do some research on here there are ample of solutions on this particular pattern query. Use `FILTER()` function if using `Excel 2019`+ or else use `INDEX()`+`AGGREGATE()` functions. To return multiple records, functions that return only first occurrence of a value wont work here. The formula which you are trying it returns unique values and doesnt exlcudes the `0`s